# Dashboard Table Won't Fill Screen

Tags: r, quarto

I'm trying to make a Quarto Dashboard and am having trouble filling the screen with a datatable. I've tried `scrollY=600`, I've tried adjusting the height in the output block--no success. I've heard about using css-style code such as `100vh-80px` but in this format of code I'd have to include `tag_head` to the top to make it work and for some reason that adds empty padding to each of my webpages, so if you can help me add that and remove the web-padding, that's also welcome This is what I've done:

````
DT::datatable(
  table_data,
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  options = list(
    scrollY = 600,
         columnDefs = list(
  list(
    targets = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7), # Adjust these indices to your numeric columns
    render = JS(
      "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
      "if(data === null || data === '') { return 'NA'; }", 
      "return type === 'display' ? Number(data).toFixed(3) : data;",
      "}"
    )
  )
)
,
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        extend = 'copy',
        className = 'btn btn-default',
        exportOptions = list(modifier = list(page = 'all'))
      ),
      list(
        extend = 'csv',
        className = 'btn btn-default',
        exportOptions = list(modifier = list(page = 'all'))
      ),
      list(
        extend = 'excel',
        className = 'btn btn-default',
        exportOptions = list(modifier = list(page = 'all'))
      )
    ),
    pageLength = 10
  ),
  class = "display",
  fillContainer = TRUE,
  rownames = FALSE
)

}, server=FALSE)

# Data {height=100%}
```{r}
DTOutput('table', height = 'auto')
````

And this is what I've gotten:

[image]